# How to give discounts in simple Ruby shopping cart?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a very simple Ruby shopping cart, and I need to be able to give discounts if a user buys certain combinations of goods. These are indicated in the @costs - if bulk is true, a user gets a discount (of :bulk_price) for buying :bulk_num of goods. I've got it making basic charges, but now I need to subtract discounts in certain cases. Here's what I have so far:

```
    class Cart
     attr_accessor :total, :costs, :item_array, :subtotal

     def initialize
      @item_array=[]
      @subtotal=0
      @costs= [{"A"=>{:price=>2, :bulk=>true, :bulk_num=>4, :bulk_price=>7}}, {"B"=>{:price=>12, :bulk=> false}},{"C"=>{:price=>1.25,:bulk=>true, :bulk_num=>6, :bulk_price=>6}}, {"D"=>{:price=>0.15, :bulk=>false}}]
     end



    def scan(*items)
     items.each do |item|
     @item_array<<item
     @costs.each do |cost|
     if cost.has_key?(item)
      @subtotal+=cost[item][:price]
     end
   end
   @subtotal
 end
end


 def total

 end

end
```

Now, I've created an array to keep track of which items are purchased, and I'd ideally like to  have the total function check the array and subtract from the subtotal if needed. Maybe I've just been staring at this too long, but I am having trouble figuring that out. Could anyone help?

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.

Comment: I can't figure out how to factor in discounts. Certain items are discounted - for example, A is $1 off if you buy 4 of them, but B is never discounted.

Comment: Im sure this thread will be closed because you don't seem to have a question other than "could you help me fix my code?", but it seem to me that items should have a property of "discount".  When you calculate the total you check if an item has a discount and then apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Indent your code properly, it will make it much easier for you in the long run.
- Remove `:total` from `attr_accessor`, it isn't needed and the generated `total` method will be overridden by the one you define later on.
- Consider making each item an object which knows its own cost, rather than looking up the cost of each item in `@costs`. Conceptually, it doesn't make sense for a "shopping cart" to keep track of all the prices of all the items in your store.
- Make your `total` method functional. Don't bother subtracting from `@subtotal` -- it will cause problems if `total` is called more than once.
- Actually, `subtotal` would also be better if you recalculate whenever needed:

  ```
  def subtotal
    @item_array.reduce(0) { |sum,item| sum + (@costs[item][:price] || 0) }
  end
  ```

It may not be obvious to you now, but writing your code "functionally", like this, makes it easier to avoid bugs. You can cache values if they are really expensive to calculate, and will be needed more than once, but in this case there's no need to.

- For `total`, you can do something like:

  ```
  def total
    result = self.subtotal
    # check which discounts apply and subtract from 'result'
    result
  end
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I'm super new at tasks like this. ok. Going to try to implement some of this to make sure I understand

Comment: Most of Ruby's awesome functional programming methods come from the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) module. Be sure to check out the documentation for it when you're learning methods like each, map, reduce, and find_all. Also, note that String, Array, Hash, and other common Ruby classes include Enumerable's methods.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question involves an exercise, I decided to change it around a bit to make some points that you might find helpful.  A few notes:

- I renamed `scan` to `checkout`, lest the former be confused with [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan)
- An order quantity is given for each item ordered, in the form of a hash that is passed to the `checkout` method;
- I changed `:bulk_price` to a unit price that applies if `:bulk` is true and the quantity ordered is at least `:bulk_num`.
- I changed `@costs` to a hash, because you need to access item names, which are now keys.
- I moved `@costs` outside the class, for two reasons.  Firstly, that data is likely to change, so it really shouldn't be hardwired in the class definiation.  Secondly, doing that provides flexibility should you want different class instances to use different `@costs`. You'll see I chose to pass that hash as an argument when creating a new class instance.
- I eliminated all your accessors.
- An exception is now raised if you enter an item name that is not a key in `@costs`.

This is the approach I took:

```
class Cart
  def initialize(costs)
    @costs= costs
  end
  def checkout(items)
    purchases = {}
    items.each do |(item, qty)|
      cost = @costs[item]
      raise ArgumentError, "Item '#{item}' not in @costs array" \
        if cost == nil
      if cost[:bulk] && qty >= cost[:bulk_num]
        tot_cost = qty.to_f * cost[:bulk_price]
        discount = qty.to_f * (cost[:price] - cost[:bulk_price])
      else
        tot_cost = qty.to_f * cost[:price]
        discount = 0.0
      end
      purchases[item] = {qty: qty, tot_cost: tot_cost, discount: discount}
    end
    purchases
  end
  def tot_cost(purchases)
    purchases.values.reduce(0) {|tot, h| tot + h[:tot_cost]}
  end
  def tot_discount(purchases)
    purchases.values.reduce(0) {|tot, h| tot + h[:discount]}
  end
end 

costs = {"A"=>{price:    2, bulk: true, bulk_num: 4, bulk_price: 1.75},
         "B"=>{price:   12, bulk: false                              },
         "C"=>{price: 1.25, bulk: true, bulk_num: 6, bulk_price: 1.00},
         "D"=>{price: 0.15, bulk: false                              }}
cart = Cart.new(costs)

purchases = cart.checkout({"A"=>6, "B"=>7, "C"=>4}) # item => quantity purchased
p purchases # => {"A"=>{:qty=>6, :tot_cost=>10.5, :discount=>1.5},
            # =>  "B"=>{:qty=>7, :tot_cost=>84.0, :discount=>0.0},
            # =>  "C"=>{:qty=>4, :tot_cost=>5.0,  :discount=>0.0}}

p cart.tot_cost(purchases)     # => 99.5
p cart.tot_discount(purchases) # =>  1.5
```